How to remove AutoSuggestBox delay / debounce?
While using the AutoSuggestBox in e.g. the WinUI 3 Gallery app, I noticed that there is some kind of debouncing on the input. So if one types fast, the results are not updated until one stops typing. However I want immediate search result updates. How can I configure that?
Screenshots:
Here I type fast. The results shown are old results (from the first letter "d") that don't get updated while typing fast:

as soon as I stop typing, the results are updated:

How to always get immediate updates, after every keystroke?

Seems pretty much baked in https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/winui3/release/1.4-stable/dxaml/xcp/dxaml/lib/AutoSuggestBox_Partial.cpp#L47

Thanks for pointing out the source code position! I included that in my Github issue at https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/9560

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:Text changed

The TextChanged event occurs whenever the content of the text box is
updated. Use the event args Reason property to determine whether the
change was due to user input. If the change reason is UserInput,
filter your data based on the input. Then, set the filtered data as
the ItemsSource of the AutoSuggestBox to update the suggestion list.

Whenever you enter a new character, the TextChanged event is triggered, and if you enter it too quickly, there will be a delay. As far as I'm concerned, this delay is normal and it is by design.
If you want to eliminate this delay, I suggest you could post the issue to Github for better help.

sad to here it's baked in, but I followed your recommendation to create a Github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/9560

Unfurtunately my issue does not receive any replys. Any way to raise some notice on it? :-)
